# EF Core - checking existence of child

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

EF Core with SQL Server backend. Parent entity contains a collection of children. In a particular case, I'm not interested in the whole collection of children, just in the information whether any child exists - I want to avoid retrieving the entire collection from a database. In T-SQL I could use a subquery with count or CROSS APPLY with TOP(1), but how to achieve this in the EF?

Let's say the model looks like this (the code is not complete for brevity):

```
class Invoice
{
  DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
  Customer Customer { get; set; }
  int CustomerId { get; set; }
  ...
  ...
  ICollection<InvoicePosition> Positions { get; set; }
}

internal virtual DbSet<Invoice> InvoiceSet { get; set; }
```

I read data this way:

```
var invoices = context.InvoiceSet
  .Include(i => i.Customer).ThanInclude(c => c.Country)
  .Where(i => ...)
  .OrderBy(i => ...)
  .Skip(...).Take(...)
  .AsAsyncEnumerable();

await foreach (var invoice in invoices)
{ ... }
```

I can include the Positions and check if any exists, but how to do this on the database side?

EDIT:
I would need additional property in the InvoiceSet - bool HasPositions:

```
class Invoice
{
  DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
  Customer Customer { get; set; }
  int CustomerId { get; set; }
  ...
  bool HasPositions { get; set; }
  ...
  ICollection<InvoicePosition> Positions { get; set; }
}
```

How to get data for this new property? If it can be done with a Linq Query, please provide an example, how to convert my reading method to the query.

Comment: Can't you just check `context.InvoicePositionSet` with any `Where()` condition you like? Why access the data indirectly when you can access them directly?

Comment: I need the list of Invoices with additional info - whether any position exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Where(i => i.Positions.Any())
```

Comment: I don't want to filter the results this way. I need all Invoices with information if there is any related Position or not.